# How to use Jenkins Multi-Configuration (Matrix) type Projects?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, continuous-integration, branding, software-product-lines

Jenkins [official Wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) for Matrix projects isn't really helping me; so I have a few questions.

We're trying to build a couple of projects that are all essentially the same, just some are being branded differently for our customers. In other words, the software / tests / etc. are all identical, except for some tweaks to turn BrandA into BrandB (or BrandC, etc.)

I figure I should be using a Matrix project to create builds for BrandA, BrandB, etc. While I haven't figured out all my steps yet (including how to rename executables after they're built) I know that I will need to pass the Brand Name to many of my Jenkins Powershell scripts during the build process, and then use that brand n the script.

How do I get these variables into my scripts? Are they automatically passed in to every build step in Jenkins? What is the variable name to use?

Finally, is there a good resource on building these multi-configuration projects in Jenkins? I can't seem to find anything comprehensive online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you usually build the job for BrandA and only occasionally for BrandB and BrandC a matrix project may not be what you want.  I recommend, instead, using a parameterized job where the brand is a parameter whose default value is BrandA. If the parameter is named `BRAND` the parameter is accessible in all of the builds and publish steps with `${BRAND}` and as an environment variable as `%BRAND%`.

I refer you to the [parameterized build wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `${BRAND}` and `%BRAND%` should work fine.

If you're using Maven, `${env.BRAND}` does this too.

There's a plugin that you can see all Environment Variables that are available to your job/build.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of that kind of process but I suggest you tu use the Copy project functionnality.

1. New Job
2. Copy From existing job

You will have a copy of your Job and you'll be able to setup easily all specific fields.